# ¿Cómo puedo usar métodos en una clase principal, de una superclase con dos clases hijas?

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Buenos días internautas.

Tengo 4 clases: Jugueteria (Principal) Muneco (superclase) MunecoBebe (subclase) MunecoAccion (subclase). En la superclase tengo un método de hallar promedios, pues necesito el total acumulado y el promedio de precios de los dos tipos de muñecos. Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo puedo usar ese método en la clase principal "Jugueteria"? Pues solo tengo herencia con MunecoBebe y MunecoAccion.
Mil gracias.

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Puedes importar la clase Muneco a Jugueteria y después crear un objeto Muneco en la clase Jugueteria

Una vez tengas creado el objeto Muneco en la clase Jugueteria puedes hacer uso de sus métodos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la clase Jugueteria que es la principal, por lógica esta clase debería tener muchos muñecos, ya sean de la clase MunecoBebe o MunecoAccion, ambos heredan de la superclase Muneco, por lo que heredan sus métodos.

Una cosa que no entiendo es que Muneco tenga el método para hallar promedios, o sea qué promedio halla? la clase Muneco representa a un muñeco no a todos, si quieres una función para hallar el precio acumulado y el promedio de precios, ambas funciones deberían estar en la clase Jugueteria, la cual tendría una lista de Muneco, en esa lista puedes agregar cualquier tipo de muñeco

Sería algo así

```
public abstract class Muneco{
    protected double precio;

    public Muneco(double precio){
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public double getPrecio(){
        return precio;
    }
}
```

```
public class MunecoBebe extends Muneco{
    
    public MunecoBebe(double precio){
        super(precio)
    }
}
```

```
public class MunecoAccion extends Muneco{
    
    public MunecoBebe(double precio){
        super(precio)
    }
}
```

```
public class Jugueteria{
    
    private ArrayList<Muneco> munecos;

    public Jugueteria(){
        this.munecos = new ArrayList<Muneco>();
    }

    public double obtenerPrecioAcumulado(){
        double total = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<munecos.size(); i++)
            total += munecos.get(i).getPrecio()
        return total;
    }

    public double obtenerPromedioPrecios(){
        double total = obtenerPrecioAcumulado();
        double promedio = total / munecos.size();
        return promedio; 
    }
}
```

El mismo método que te devuelve el precio acumulado lo usarías para hallar el promedio.